# How do I present UIImagePickerController scene as initial scene?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I created a `UIViewController` scene and set its custom class to `StoryBookPageImagePickerController` but when I ran the program, and grant access to photos, I see a header and a black screen with no photos for selection.

```
class StoryBookPageImagePickerController : UIImagePickerController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

override init() {
    super.init()
    self.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    self.mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypesForSourceType(.Camera)!
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.delegate = self
    println("Loaded image picker")

}

//MARK: Delegates
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

}
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you cannot subclass UIImagePickerController. From the docs:

IMPORTANT

The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode only. This class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified, with one exception. You can assign a custom view to the cameraOverlayView property and use that view to present additional information or manage the interactions between the camera interface and your code.